# Remoting. How to make code run just on server side

Tags: c#, remoting

I am not very familiar with remoting.

1) We have WinForm client/server application. C# 3.5
2) I am using a 3rd API in my application.

Do to configuration issues with this API. (I can't read its dll.config files client side)

I would like to keep the execution of all this code server side, where I can currently get it to work.

Even though I have the code server side it's still erroring out looking for the dll.config from the calling client.

How can I make a client request but have everything just run on the server?